# How can i club all student_id together and make a sub array()

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my Array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 22
                [skill_id] => 3
                [gd_score] => 4
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 22
                [skill_id] => 63
                [gd_score] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 23
                [skill_id] => 3
                [gd_score] => 9
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 23
                [skill_id] => 128
                [gd_score] => 10
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 24
                [skill_id] => 63
                [gd_score] => 10
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [student_id] => 24
                [skill_id] => 128
                [gd_score] => 2
            )
    )
```

How can I club all student_id together and make a sub array()?

Comment: So you just want to get all `student_id`'s inside one array?!

Comment: for single student  has set of {skill_id, gd_score}

Comment: Disregard my answer, I misunderstood your question. I deleted the answer.

Comment: Please show us the code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code you'll get an array with all the students. The index will be the student id and it will contain a set of all {skill_id,gd_score}'s.

```
$students = array();
foreach ($array as $row){
    $student_id = $row['student_id'];
    $students[$student_id][] = array('skill_id'=>$row['skill_id'],'gd_score'=>$row['gd_score']);
}
print_r($students);
```